# How to bind default value in mat-radio-group angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my case it needs to active option 01 as default selection. It is working with checked=true property, but value is not binding with the formControlName="options", it is binding when user select any option. if no any user selection options value shows as "null".

```html
  <div class="row">
      <mat-radio-group formControlName="options">
        <mat-radio-button checked=true  value="1">Option 01</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button  value="2">Option 02</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
```

Please kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

What you want to do is to remove the `checked` and instead set the preselected value to your `formControl`, so when you build your form:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    options: ['1']
  })
}
```

and then you just remove the `checked` attribute:

```html
<mat-radio-group formControlName="options">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 01</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button  value="2">Option 02</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Sadly setting value 0 on radio-group makes all radio buttons unselected. Even tough one of my radio-button has value of 0. So I have to change from enum index values to enum string values to make it work correctly. I suppose increasing each value by +1 will also work.

Comment: I want the radio button to be selected by default. For this, I'm using checked=true but it's not working. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @AnilKumar use 'checked' only and that will work. Example '<mat-radio-button value="1" checked>Option 1</mat-radio-button>'

Comment: great catch with checked attribute.

Comment: Why the hell it doesn't work with numbers and I'm forced to use strings in the enum? That's stupid.

Answer (score 6):

Alternate way:

```
 this.optionFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  options: new FormControl('1'); // the value type (string) should match
 })
```

--

```
  <div class="row" [formGroup]="optionFormGroup">
   <mat-radio-group formControlName="options">
     <mat-radio-button checked value="1">Option 01</mat-radio-button>
     <mat-radio-button  value="2">Option 02</mat-radio-button>
   </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
```

Comment: When using a mat-radio-group within a component you need some way to define the FormGroup.  Usually I see people do this with `mat-form-field` in material.  This doesn't work for `mat-radio-group`.  However, this solution works. In my case I used `<ng-container [formGroup]="parentForm">` as opposed to a div.

Answer (score 1):

This will default select "yes" option from radio button options.

```html
  <form [formGroup]="optionsFormGroup">
        <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="75px">
          <mat-grid-tile>
            <label>Option</label>
            <mat-radio-group formControlName="statusOptions" class="m-l-5">
              <mat-radio-button class="m-r-5" value="yes">Yes</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button class="m-r-5" value="no">No</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
            <mat-icon class="info-icon">help_outline
            </mat-icon>
          </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </form>
```

```js
initFormControls() {
    this.optionsFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      statusOptions: ['yes'],
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is look like other answers, but uses boolean values

**ts**

```
form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  enable: ['']
});

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form.get('enable').setValue(false);
}
```

**template**

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="enable">
   <mat-radio-button [value]="true" color="primary">Enable</mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button [value]="false" color="primary" class="radio">Disable</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `mat-radio-group` appears to be broken. It does not work with `formGroupName` the way I expected it to.

Hence, I am using `form.patchValue()` directly in my template.

```js
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  choice: new FormControl(1),
});
```

```html
<mat-radio-group formGroupName="choiceType" 
                 (change)="form.patchValue({choice: $event.value})">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="1" checked>Single-choice</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="2">Multi-choice</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```